# Change view after playing video

Tags: iphone, view, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsnotifications, nsnotificationcenter

My Video works when I click my play button, and I know the code for my view change works. I just can't seem to get the view to change after my video is done playing, not sure what is going wrong. Any ideas to get the view to change once the video is done playing?

My code to play movie

```
-(IBAction)playMovie:(id)sender {
NSString *movieUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie_1666" ofType:@"m4v"]; 
playerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:movieUrl]];
//Smoothe Transition
//[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playerController];
//Instant Transistion
[self presentModalViewController:playerController animated:NO];
playerController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
playerController.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
playerController.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
[playerController.moviePlayer play];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playbackFinished:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:playerController]; }
```

My method to change views

```
- (void)playbackFinished:(NSNotification*) notification {
MPMoviePlayerController *playerController = [notification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
 removeObserver:self
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object:playerController];

View2 *view2 = [[View2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"View2" bundle:nil];
View2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:view2 animated:YES]; }
```

EDIT:
My Notification object was wrong and wasn't triggering my playbackFinished method
this change fixes that.

```
- (void)playbackFinished:(NSNotification*) notification {
playerController = [notification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
 removeObserver:self
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object:playerController];
```

I also put this in my header file to make it global for use in my playbackFinished method

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerController;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the movie play finished, dismiss the `playerController` view without animation. Also check, whether you are presenting the `View2` in main thread.

**Edit:**
Dismiss the `playerController` by

```
[playerController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Comment: Not quite sure how to make the magic happen. I'm not sure how to dismiss playerController, I can't release it. Also how do I present View2 in the main thread?

Comment: I have updated my answer with code to dismiss the playerController.